# How to change the color of selected text in the HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highlighting

I want to know how can I change the  highlight color of selected text?

Here is by default?

[image]

And I want something like this:

[image]

It should be noted I'm not talking about `font-family`. I  just want to change the highlight color .., How can I do that?

Comment: What is the type of content ? Contenteditable, textarea, input, div (*NodeElement*)... ?

Comment: @HorsSujet It is `<p>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
::selection {
  background: #ffb7b7;
}
::-moz-selection {
  background: #ffb7b7;
}
```

Also for more information you can see [this](https://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/).

Answer (score 3):

## Example :

```css
p::selection {
  background: #FEAA90;
}
p::-moz-selection {
  background: #FEAA90;
}
```

```html
<p>Click on "Run code snippet" and select this text.</p>
```

## Support : http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-selection

[image: Can I use ::selection ?]

Answer (score 1):

You can do by  [::selection Pseudo-element](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp)

For example:

```
::selection {
    color: red;
    background: #FEAA90;
}
```